# What does INH as an IC pin label mean?

Tags: integrated-circuit, multiplexer, pins, cad

While using a CAD model for a 74HC4051D multiplexer which I downloaded from [SnapEDA](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/74HC4051D%2C653/Nexperia%20USA%20Inc./view-part/?ref=search&t=74hc4051) I noticed that pin 6 is labelled INH rather than E bar (or Enable) as I anticipated from the [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2024221.pdf).

**What does INH stand for?**

[[image: CAD part schematic]] [image: datasheet pin diagram]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are representing that signal as active-high Inhibit (INH), which is logically equivalent to active-low Enable (EN#).